# Help Rectify vs Help Rectifying

Tags: grammaticality, tense, idiomatic-language

> It will be great if someone can help **rectify** it.
>
> It will be great if someone can help **rectifying** it.

May I know which one above is grammatical?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After the verb "to help" comes infinitive: **(He helps me do this)**

You can also use the preposition (to):
**(He helps me to do this)**

Your first sentence is the correct one

Comment: The second one is ungrammatical, but _We need help rectifying it_ is grammatical, because _help_ can be a noun, too; here it's used as object of _help_, with a modifying gerund clause, meaning _help in rectifying it_.